# Problems with sending and recieving strings to and from text boxes

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I was having issue with `SendKeys` to send long strings to a textbox. (Also same with Actions and sendkeys) so I tried JavaScript Executor.

JSE (JavaScript Executor ) sends strings to textboxes perfectly fine but when I click the validate button it doesn't recognize that there is text in the textbox and throws an error that the textbox is empty. I found the same when I tried to retrive strings back from textboxes, it returns null value.

This is my code:

```
public void EnterLicenceNumber(string licenceNumber)
{
    driver.WaitElementToExists(txtLicenceNumber,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value='" + licenceNumber + "';", txtLicenceNumber);
    txtLicenceNumber.Click();
}
```

I have tried a number of different options but nothing works. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Can you show more code so that we can get a clear picture

Comment: Assigning a string to `value` using JSE is not the same as entering the text into the field in some (many?) cases.

Comment: HI I am trying to use send key to enter serial number with code above. and example of serial is : 998D6067-619D-4365-8D97-D6ACFF3BCC8C.  Problem is it does enter key in box but (-) in between characters are getting misplaced. I think its due to some validation on textbox may be? See below details

Comment: <input type="text" name="serial" ng-model="$ctrl.serial" ng-change="$ctrl.editInput($ctrl.serial,'')" required="" ng-pattern="/^([a-z]|[0-9]|-)+$/i" maxlength="36" class="ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched">